# How would I be able to assign a random integer to a variable?

Tags: python, variables, random, integer

I have been trying to assign a random number to a variable, such as health or luck but it never seems to work as when I print the variable it just says it's not defined. I would greatly appreciate any help with this. Thank you very much.

```
from random import randint

def ageroll():
    age= int(input("How old will you be?"))
    if age <= 0:
        print("Input a valid number from 1 to 120")
        ageroll()
    elif age <= 18:
        health = randint(1,4)
        agility = randint(4,8)
        strength = randint(1,2)
        luck = randint(1,10)
        endurance = randint(2,4)
        intelligence = randint(1,5)
        charm = randint(1,7)
        return(health,agility,strength,luck,endurance,intelligence,charm)
    elif age <= 35:
        health = randint(4,10)
        agility = randint(5,9)
        strength = randint(5,10)
        luck = randint(1,10)
        endurance = randint(4,8)
        intelligence = randint(3,10)
        charm = randint(4,7)
    elif age <= 56:
        health = randint(4,8)
        agility = randint(3,6)
        strength = randint(3,10)
        luck = randint(1,10)
        endurance = randint(5,8)
        intelligence = randint(5,10)
        charm = randint(6,10)
    elif age <= 78:
        health = randint(2,5)
        agility = randint(2,5)
        strength = randint(2,6)
        luck = randint(1,10)
        endurance = randint(1,4)
        intelligence = randint(6,10)
        charm = randint(5,6)
    elif age <= 101:
        health = randint(1,5)
        agility = randint(1,4)
        strength = randint(1,4)
        luck = randint(4,10)
        endurance = randint(3,9)
        intelligence = randint(3,10)
        charm = randint(4,7)
    elif age <= 120:
        health = randint(1,2)
        agility = randint(1,3)
        strength = randint(1,4)
        luck = 10
        endurance = randint(6,8)
        intelligence = randint(10,10)
        charm = randint(6,10)
    else:
        print("Input a valid number from 1 to 120")
        ageroll()
```

Comment: You only return anything when `age` <= 18.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  Specifically, the code you posted does not elicit the problem you describe.

Comment: I'd add a print statement under the options to see if it's selecting any of them. i.e., "elif age <= 56", print "age is ", age to see that it entered the elif block. @Daniel is right, you're only returning from one of the blocks. These variables are staying local...you're going to want to return at the end of your if/else block

Comment: As an experiment, wherever you see a call to `randinit`, replace it by a non-random number (e.g. the fixed constant 5) and see if you observe the same problem. You will. This will show you that the problem has nothing at all to do with the fact that you are trying to assign *random* integers to a variable but is instead a matter of *how* (and, specifically, *where*) you are doing the assignments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return your variables, and assign this return-value to a variable again, to use it:

```
from random import randint

PROPERTY_RANGES = [
    (18, dict(health=(1,4), agility=(4,8), strength=(1,2), luck=(1,10), endurance=(2,4), intelligence=(1,5), charm=(1,7))),
    (35, dict(health=(4,10), agility=(5,9), strength=(5,10), luck=(1,10), endurance=(4,8), intelligence=(3,10), charm=(4,7))),
    (56, dict(health=(4,8), agility=(3,6), strength=(3,10), luck=(1,10), endurance=(5,8), intelligence=(5,10), charm=(6,10))),
    (78, dict(health=(2,5), agility=(2,5), strength=(2,6), luck=(1,10), endurance=(1,4), intelligence=(6,10), charm=(5,6))),
    (101, dict(health=(1,5), agility=(1,4), strength=(1,4), luck=(4,10), endurance=(3,9), intelligence=(3,10), charm=(4,7))),
    (120, dict(health=(1,2), agility=(1,3), strength=(1,4), luck=(10,10), endurance=(6,8), intelligence=(10,10), charm=(6,10))),
]

def ageroll():
    while True:
        age = int(input("How old will you be?"))
        if 0 < age <= 120:
            break
        print("Input a valid number from 1 to 120")
    for max_age, values in PROPERTY_RANGES:
        if age <= max_age:
            break
    return {k: randint(*r) for k, r in values.items()}

properties = ageroll()
print(properties['health'])
```